# Can I put the session token in the body to protect against CSRF?

Tags: csrf

Say I have a user with an associated session token. This user wants to delete his account, and so he goes to its associated link. I, trying to protect my users and myself from CSRF attacks, have it so when the user clicks a link and makes the DELETE request, I send that user's session token in the request body. Any other sites couldn't possibly know the session cookie, and therefore couldn't send it in the request body. On the receiving end, the server checks to make sure that the session cookie and the session token in the body are the same.

Why doesn't this work? The explanations I've heard have been way more intricate and I just can't see why the aforementioned process wouldn't work. I know I must be overlooking something!

Comment: Welcome to sec.SE. It would be good if you can add more information about the resources you referred. This would give more context to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basics of CSRF protection**

Most CSRF protection mechanisms work on a basic principle that the HTML form being submitted and the server should have shared secret between them. When the form is submitted to the server, this shared secret is used to identify if the request originated from a legitimate page. There is no way for malicious sites to access this shared secret if it is present in the request body. (Obviously cookies cant be used to store this secret as browsers transmit them to the target domain irrespective of the origin of the page.)

**Double submitted cookie**

The prevention method that you have described is called [double submitted cookie](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Double_Submit_Cookie). In this the shared secret is sent using both the cookie and form parameter. The server only has to compare the two values to filter out forged requests.

**Why does it not work?**

It does work. The session token is indeed a shared secret between the browser and the server. However the session token's primary job is to track the user's authenticated session. A session token present in the cookie is protected by cookie flags such as HTTPonly. This prevents JavaScript from accessing the session cookie, which in turn prevents session ID theft in case of an XSS vulnerability.

**Having the session token in the request body of every HTML form increases the attack surface** as the session token can be extracted by exploiting a script injection vulnerability. Hence it is good practice to have a dedicated CSRF token do the job.